# Bootstrap3 left vertical menu doesn't scroll so cannot see full sub menu items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 to make left vertical menu.  Here is a small part of my navbar code...

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
   <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
      <li class="sidebar-search">
         <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
            </span>
         </div>
         <!-- /input-group -->
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/Admin"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Address Book<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
         <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
            <li>
               <a href="/MH_Admin_Addressbook/index_people">People List</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="/MH_Admin_Addressbook/people_create">New Person</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

The above results in a menu lie this:

[image]

If I click on a menu item, sub menu items will appear, however, if the list is too long it is cut short and there is no way to scroll.  How do I fix this?

Comment: can you make a codepen or something so I can look into you problem? I've tried to repeat the issue, but it all seams works to me

Comment: cannot get the issue... your code snippet works fine... can you modify your snippet to replicate the actual issue you are stuck with.

Comment: Even if it goes off the bottom of the screen, you canna roll down to it?

Comment: Here it is... https://codepen.io/spreaderman/pen/YzGxKvp. For example, if you expand SETTINGS, the bottom of the menu disappears.